# How to use Global Resources in a Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization, embedded-resource

I use the Global Resources feature, not only to centralize all my output strings but to make it easy when using Localization (witch is almost 90% of the time).

But I spread out my project into, not only the ASP.NET website, but with 2 Library projects as well.

my question is:

> How can I use the **ASP.NET Global Resource file** in those Library projects?

as If I do

```
Resources.MyFilename.MyResourceStringName
```

the Library as no knowledge of the `MyFilename` class

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-08-12_1307.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-08-12_1307.png)

What should I do in this cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your going to have to use the ResourceManager class to accomplish this.

[MSDN Resource Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx)

Comment: Got it... I just passed the ResourceManager that the Resource file is assign to, like: `ResourceManager rm = Resources.Strings.ResourceManager;` and then `myClass cl = new myClass(rm);`